# Angular Material DatePicker not Changing when Moment locale does

Tags: angular, typescript, datepicker, angular-material

Details: Angular Material 7 DatePicker with moment js

Problem: When the language of my web application is changed, the datepickers do not change locale.

Desired result: Every time I change the language in my application, my date pickers should also change to that locales format and language. At the moment, I need to toggle between dd/MM/yyyy and MM/dd/yyyy.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? I am new to moment and cannot seem to get the formatting done properly.

Code:

HTML

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>From date</mat-label>
  <input name="fromDate" [min]="minDate" [max]="maxDate" [formControl]="displayFromDate" 
                     matInput [matDatepicker]="fromDatePicker">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="fromDatePicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #fromDatePicker disabled="false"></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Some of my translation service code that changes the moment locale:
the lang parameter will either be 'en' or 'fr' and is toggled by a switch that the app is listening to.

```
public use(lang: string): void {
  this._currentLang = lang;
  moment.locale(lang);      
  this.currentLang$.next(this.currentLang);
}
```

App.module.ts

```
import { MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS, MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';

import { DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';

import localeFr from '@angular/common/locales/fr';
import localeEn from '@angular/common/locales/en';

registerLocaleData(localeFr);
registerLocaleData(localeEn);
```

...

```
imports: [
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
ReactiveFormsModule,
```

...

```
{ provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
{ provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS },],
```

Component code using the datepicker:

```
this.translationService.currentLang$.subscribe(currentLang => {      
  this.displayFromDate = new FormControl({ value: moment(this.displayFromDate.value).format(), disabled: true });
  console.log('displayFromDate', this.displayFromDate);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I missed this in the angular documentation. If anyone else comes across this digging for the same information, make sure you're using the data adapter to set your locale.

```
constructor(private adapter: DateAdapter<any>) {}

toggleLocale() {
  this.adapter.setLocale(moment.locale());
}
```

Comment: this was the solution. no need to add anything else, just used this in the app.component and it all was fine. only, the moment didn't work but I was already using navigator to fetch the current lang

Answer (score 0):

**`You can call moment.tz.guess() with an optional boolean argument "ignoreCache". If set to true, the cache will be ignored and overwritten with the new value.`**

Moment doc URL - https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/

Working example - https://codesandbox.io/s/material-date-locale-jyylz

Answer (score 0):

**I solved all, all my datetime problems like this:**

```
npm remove moment
npm remove @angular/material-moment-adapter
npm i @angular/material-luxon-adapter
```

in app.module.ts:

```
import { LuxonDateAdapter, MAT_LUXON_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, MAT_LUXON_DATE_FORMATS } from '@angular/material-luxon-adapter';

providers: [
     {provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE, useValue: 'default'},
     {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: LuxonDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE, MAT_LUXON_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS]},
     {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_LUXON_DATE_FORMATS}
    ]
```

Edit chrome://settings/languages for tests